# Apply a style to a list item when a user clicks any list item in an unordered list using react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

I am trying to change the background color of a list item that a user clicks on in react.

Here is what I have tried:

```
import React from "react";

function LandingPage(){

  let colorChange = () =>{
    let em = document.getElementsByClassName(em);
    for(var i = 0; i < em.length; i++){
      if(em[i] = 0){
        console("yes")
      }
      else{
        console.log("no")
      }
    }

  }
  return(<>
    <ul>
      <li className="em">red</li>
      <li className="em">blue</li>
      <li className="em">Yellow</li>
    </ul>    
  </>)
}

export default LandingPage;
```

I have created a function colorChange to loop through the list items; however, I havent been able to get it to work

Comment: You mentioned React, but I don't see any React in your example code. This looks like regular Javascript.

Comment: @GreenGiant that's the code in my react component

Comment: Oh my apologies. Somehow I failed to notice the JSX in your return statement.

Answer (score 1):

1. First you need to store the name of the colors you wish to display inside the ul in an array called colorsListToDisplay.
2. Next create a react state called coloredItems in which we will store the name of the colors that have been applied to list items that have been clicked on till now.
3. Then loop through the colorsListToDisplay array and create an li for each color inside of it and attach an onClick listener to each.
4. Inside the onClick listener we'll call the colorChange function and we'll pass the current item's color to the function.
5. Inside the function we'll check to see if the color has already been added to the list of applied colors(coloredItems), if it has, just remove if from the list using the filter method and if not, just add it to the list.
6. Lastly for the className, let's say the li is supposed to turn blue on click, check if the value "blue" exists inside the coloredItems array, if it does then set the className to blue and if not set the className to "black".

Inside the styles.css file define the classes for each color like this:

```
    .black{
      color: black;
    }
   .blue {
      color: blue;
    }  
    .red {
      color: red;
    }
    .yellow {
      color: yellow;
    }
```

and the react code will be like this:

```
import "./styles.css";
import React, { useState } from "react";
function LandingPage() {
  const [coloredItems, setColoredItems] = useState([]);
  const colorsListToDisplay = ["red", "blue", "yellow"];

  const colorChange = (e, index, color) => {
    const itemIndex = coloredItems.findIndex((item) => item=== 
      color);
    // if index is -1 -> doesn't exist
    if (itemIndex === -1) {
      setColoredItems((prev) => [...prev,  color ]);
    } else setColoredItems((prev) => prev.filter((item) => item!== color));
  };

  return (
    <ul>
      {colorsListToDisplay.map((color, index) => (
        <li
          key={index}
          onClick={(e) => colorChange(e, color)}
          className={coloredItems.find((item) => item === color) ? 
          color : "black"}
        >
          {color}
        </li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
}
export default LandingPage;
```